# outdenting a bibliography (negative/hanging indent) in Context

Tags: bibliographies, lists, enumerate, indentation, context

I'm trying to get this outdent/negative effect for enumeration/list/bibliography in Context: first line is full width, and consecutive lines are indented.

[image: outdenting or negative indenting for lists]

Thanks in advance

### Edit 1

Seems like a start but I know need to get read of the left margin of the list.

```
\defineitemgroup[biblio]
\setupitemgroup [biblio] [each] [packed] [
    leftmargin=1cm,
    indenting={-1cm, yes},
    % leftmargindistance=0pt,
    % textdistance=0pt,
    symbol={},
    % distance=0pt,
]


\starttext

\input knuth

\startbiblio
    \dorecurse{3}{\item \input knuth}
\stopbiblio
\stoptext

\input knuth
```